# How to style the contents of a class only if those contents are a 5 to 6 digit number

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to add a class to style the contents of a bootstrap class (the specific class is .col-xs-8), but what I need is for this style to be applied ONLY IF the contents of .col-xs-8 is a 5 or 6 digit number.

The real life scenario is as follows:

My company has an online store that generates and manages orders (we sell signage). When someone places an order, a job number is generated. I cannot find the code that actually generates the number, so I am needing to add a style to the outer class(.col-xs-8) so that I can style the job number separate from all of the other content that is generated into a .col-xs-8 class.

This is the php that is generating the job number. The "$order['po']" is content that I am trying to style.

```
$data = array(  
  'PO #:' => $order['po'],  
  'Date:' => date("m/d/Y g:ia",strtotime($order['orderDate'])),  
  'Address:' => $order['add'],  
  'City:' => $city,  
  'Zip Code:' => $order['zip'],  
  'Status:' => $order['status'],  
  'Service Type:' => $service_type,  
  'Size:' => $order['size'],  
  'Sign Type:' => $sign_type,  
  'Sign Text:' => $sign_text,  
  'Details:'=> str_replace("\n","<br />\n",$order['details']),  
  'Broker 1:' => $broker1,  
  'Broker 2:' =>    $broker2,  
  //'Broker 3' =>   $broker3,  
  'Invoice #:' => '<span id="invNumDisplay"   style="width:100px;">'.$order['invoiceNumber'].'</span>&nbsp;' .$editInv,  
 // 'Has Rider' => $order['rider'],  
 // 'Rider Text' => $order['riderText'],  
);
```

Sorry if this post isn't up to the usual standards. This is my first time posting on stack, and I am not an experienced back-end coder.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Add an `if` statement in your code and it should give you the result you want? To get the string length use `strlen()`

Comment: Hey Joel, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you break this down into a bit more concrete example of what you're trying to do? I understand there's a PO number involved and if it's 5 or 6 digits you want to apply a class. Can you show us the before html and after you'd like to see for a specific example?

Comment: So let's say the generated number is "547735". This is the html that is generated by the PHP above:  

    <div class="col-xs-8"> 547735</div>

What I want is to find that specific class (based on the fact that there is a 5-6 digit number within it) and then add another class to it so I can style the text (I'll call this class 'TextStyle'). Something like this: 

    <div class="col-xs-8 TextStyle">547735</div>

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. So far, I understand that you are building an array in PHP from results you obtained from another PHP script( in the back-end ).. What I am not seeing is your HTML.. How are you parsing this array in your front-end? Please provide us with some of the HTML you have so we can start piecing it together with more context.

Comment: Here is the html code:  
  
        <div class="row">  
          <div class="form-group">  
            <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" style="margin:0;"><b><?=$name?></b></label>  
            <div class="col-xs-8">  
                <?=$value?>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
          </div>  
  
  And by the way, I can't even figure out how to code my damn comment. Sorry about that

Comment: Also, I understand bootstrap uses `col-xs-*` to create side-by-side responsive columns/grid.. With that said, I am assuming your end result should be a side by side column table with each column being an order?  again, to understand it better, your HTML would help. To provide the HTML, you can click "edit" in your intial answer, and add the code there

Comment: in the HTML you provided in your comment, you have a variable `$value`, so if this is `5` or `6`, then you want to apply a class correct?

Comment: @CodeGodie, pretty close. If that value is a number that is either 5 or 6 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your HTML, I would do this:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 <?= (strlen($value) == 5 || strlen($value) == 6 )?"classname":"" ?> "> <?= $value ?> </div>
```

This will result in either:

if `$value` has 5 or 6 characters

```
<div class="col-xs-8 classname"> <?= $value ?> </div>
```

if not

```
<div class="col-xs-8"> <?= $value ?> </div>
```

Comment: ok, i think I got it. Would this be what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems very close. Did you see that it would be for any number that is either 5 or 6 digits long?